# how to config databricks unity catalog shared cluster that allows spark functions w/o throwing Py4JSecurityException

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

How do I set up a single large cluster w/unity catalog that multiple users can connect to and allows spark functions to run without throwing a Py4JSecurityException error?

It doesn't even let you check if a table exists using
spark.catalog.tableExists()

The code runs in a single user cluster, but it's not feasible to have dozens/100s of individual clusters for users. They'll be sitting idle for 70-80% of the time, and large queries will fail because they'll be resource limited by the individual single node/user clusters..

I've migrated to unity catalog from a 'no isolation shared' hive metastore cluster

I can't wrap my head around a distributed platform forcing me to create individual machines for every user